# Xunit mock TokenClient call

Tags: c#, identityserver4

```
var tokenclient = new TokenClient(int a, int b);

 var response = await tokenclient.RequestAuthorizationCodeAsync(request.name, request.age);
```

How do i mock RequestAuthorizationCodeAsync?
I'm using Xunit

Answer (score 0):

Easiest approach would be to wrap `TokenClient` in your own interface or class with virtual methods and mock.

```
public class TokenClientEx
    {
        private TokenClient _tokenClient;

        public TokenClientEx(TokenClient tokenClient)
        {
            _tokenClient = tokenClient;
        }

        public virtual Task<TokenResponse> RequestAuthorizationCodeTokenAsync(string code, string redirectUri, string codeVerifier = null,
            IDictionary<string, string> parameters = null, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default)
        {
            return _tokenClient.RequestAuthorizationCodeTokenAsync(code, redirectUri, codeVerifier, parameters, cancellationToken);
        }
    }
```

You could mock httpclient parameter of `TokenClient` and test, but this is already tested on [lib](https://github.com/IdentityModel/IdentityModel/blob/main/test/UnitTests/TokenClientRequestTests.cs#L147) and its safe to assume it works fine.